# Using the Constant Function Theorem to prove the Increasing Function Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, education

I quote Thomas W.Tucker:

> ... By the way, I view the Constant Function Theorem as even more basic than the IFT. It would be nice to use it as our theoretical cornerstone, but I know of no way to use it to get the IFT. ...

$\,$ from $\,$ [Rethinking Rigor in Calculus: The Role of the Mean Value Theorem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2974788.pdf) - The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 104, No. 3 (Mar., 1997), page 233 $ \,$ where IFT means Increasing Function Theorem.

For convenience:

- *Increasing function* $f$ means that $\,$if $c \lt d$, then $f(c) \le f(d)$;
- IFT: if $f'(x) \ge 0$ on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$;
- CFT: if $f'(x)=0$ on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$.

Is it impossible to get the IFT from the CFT ?

Comment: In the paper referred to, the author in the discussion refers to what he calls Theorem 1c as SIFT, strictly increasing function theorem. Then later he (I think mistakenly) refers again to Theorem 1c as the constant function theorem (CFT). However I think it more likely that CFT refers to his Theorem 1b, which says if $f'$ is 0 on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$. It would indeed be tricky to derive IFT from this.

Comment: @Tony Piccolo : I'd think it good if you were to include exact quotes of IFT and CFT in your posted question. I had to look them up in Tucker's paper, and even there had a doubt (see my previous comment). In my opinion the posed question would be better if it were self-contained.

Comment: @coffeemath: you are right, there is a misprint; CFT refers to Theorem 1b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be nice to have a clear statement of what it means to "get from CFT to IFT".  In the most standard sense of logical implication, we have two true statements $A$ and $B$, so the statement "$A \implies B$" is certainly true.  But surely something other than this trivial observation is meant.

One nice way of construing statements like this is developed in Jim Propp's article [Real Analysis in Reverse](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4483v4.pdf).  Namely, both assertions are meaningful when applied to an arbitrary ordered field, so one can explore the class of ordered fields in which they hold.  It turns out that many, but not all, of the interesting theorems in calculus imply the Dedekind completeness of the ordered field, so *only* hold in the real numbers.  That is the case here, as is treated in Propp's article: a **gap** in an ordered field leads to a locally constant function which is not constant, so CFT implies Dedekind completeness (hence so does IFT).

Does the above argument -- i.e., showing that CFT implies Dedekind completeness and then giving, say, the usual proof of the Mean Value Theorem and then deducing IFT -- count as "getting from CFT to IFT"?  I would guess not.  But then, as I pointed out above, it's less than clear what this "getting from" business really means.

Note that exactly this issue comes up in $\S 5.1$ of [this note of mine on real induction](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0973v1.pdf), in which I suggest a rather inadequate meaning for equivalence of theorems like this by saying that each one "immediately implies" the other...whatever that means!

Comment: I actually find the acceptance of this answer somewhat disappointing.  I suspect there's more going on in the question than my answer addresses.

Comment: you say that the question is not well posed ... and I agree.

Comment: @Tony: okay, but...just because something is not well-posed doesn't mean that it *couldn't be made so*.  I guess I feel like you may be giving up too easily.

Comment: I promise I'll think how to modify the question.

Answer (score 0):

IFT to CFT: consider $f(x)$ and $g(x) := -f(x)$ s.t. $f(x)$ is differentiable... (the standard set-up). Now, $f'(x) \ge 0$, $g'(x) \le 0$, so $f$ is increasing, and $g$ is decreasing.
(All that jazz^ to show that we get decreasing functions if $g'(x) \ge 0$)
Now, if $h(x)$ also differentiable and so on, $h'(x) = 0$, we have

$h'(x) = 0 \implies h'(x) \ge 0 \implies h \text{ is increasing}$, i.e, $h(x) \ge h(y)$ if $x>y$

$h'(x) = 0 \implies h'(x) \le 0 \implies h \text{ is decreasing}$, i.e., $h(x)\le h(y)$ if $x>y$

so if $x>y$, putting both inequalities together: $h(x) = h(y)$ (note this is for all $x$ and $y$), so $h$ must be constant as it equals a constant value $h(x)$ for all values of $x$.

I know this isn't the most rigorous answer, but you can fill in the details.